# Why I can't write a file in /tmp/ even when it is root:root and has "t" flag?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am using the `postgres` user to execute some special commands. For that, I am trying the following:

```
$ sudo su - postgres  
postgres$ ls -l /tmp
drwxrwxrwt  13 root root  4096 jun  8 12:20 tmp
```

```
PGPASSWORD=mypasswordhere time pg_dump --username=postgres --no-password -f /tmp/myfilehere.sql mydatabasehere
pg_dump: [archiver] could not open output file "/tmp/myfilehere.sql": Permiso denegado  
Command exited with non-zero status 1  
0.25user 0.06system 0:02.04elapsed 15%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 58064maxresident)k  
0inputs+0outputs (0major+5110minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

**Question:** Why can't I write in `/tmp` with user `postgres`? Noticing the sticky flag is set on `/tmp`.

Comment: I just read the title, well the problem is that because of the sticky bit only root can write to the file (if your command is writing to it) or that `postgres` hasn't the read permission set for the file (i.e. `postgres` is not in the root's group / the read flag for the group on the file is not set)

Comment: You're right. My question was bc I did not know I already created the file, but under different user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sticky bit will prevent any user other than the owner of file (and owner of directory and root) to remove/rename any file inside the directory containing sticky bit. If any user does not have permission to write then he would not be able to create any file in `/tmp` or any other directory having sticky bit set, same goes for read and execute operations.

In your case if `postgres` has sufficient permission to read/write/execute files in `/tmp` then he can do that otherwise you need to set the appropriate permissions manually.

**Example :**

```
drwxrwxrwt   7 root   root    4096 Jun  9 00:41 tmp

$ sudo chmod o-rwx /tmp

drwxrwx--T   7 root   root    4096 Jun  9 00:41 tmp

$ touch /tmp/foo.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/tmp/foo.txt’: Permission denied

$ sudo chmod o+rwx /tmp

$ touch /tmp/foo.txt

$ ls -l /tmp/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Jun  9 00:50 foo.txt
```

Comment: It was an 8th layer error (i.e. stuff between the keyboard and chair). However your answer helped me to notice it was an 8th layer error (with my script I created the same file with another user).